# Continue loading when pressing 'esc' key in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> in most browsers stops the request. However I want to override this and continue the request.

I have tried the following but no success.

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Stops what request? You mean, stops your initial page load, or you mean it stops some other request being made *from* your page?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
document.attachEvent("onkeydown", keydown);
function keydown() {
     // esc
     if (event.keyCode = 27) {
          event.returnValue = false;
          event.keyCode = 0;
    }
}
```